# Tag filters emails show meta posts when nothing new matches filter

Tags: bug, email, tag-filters

For the last few weeks I've been getting emails like this when one of my tag filters doesn't match anything new:

[image: meta posts in tag filter email]

I'm seeing a bunch of meta posts and nothing that is actually matching the filter.  Before the last few weeks it seemed to not generate an email if nothing new matched the filter since the previous email.

Here is the tag filter:

[image: my new hobbies tag filter]

When I click through to the [tag filter on the website](https://stackexchange.com/filters/204455/new-hobbies) I see questions that I have previously gotten emails about.  I haven't seen meta posts showing up after I click through to there, the meta stuff only shows up in the emails.

I'm guessing that this is only happening to me on this particular tag filter because my others are for higher volume things that always have something that fits the criteria.

Comment: This is still happening a few times per week to me.

Comment: It is not happening as often, but it just happened again today.